# Angularjs and Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, html

on my html header i have this two lines:

```
<html>
<head>
<!--bootstrap-->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!--angular-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

but if i have this two lines at the same time, bootstrap doesn't work. If i comment the line of the angularjs and leave the line for bootstrap alone, bootstrap will process correctly and format the elements on the page.

i have already tried change the order on headers and add diferent links to download the files, but nothing have worked.

Anyone knows a solution for both to work at the same time?

Thanks

Comment: that throw some error? can you put some jsfiddle or plunkr to chech this, beacuse i not see anything bad

Comment: `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery`, implement Jquery first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the followed error in your console:

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
```

So just do it as follow, and you get no errors:

```
<!--Jquery-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--bootstrap-->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!--angular-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

This must work :)